# How does cout << (i > 0); makes it equal to 1?

Tags: c++, cout

in the statement, `cout << (i>0)`, where `i` is positive, and greater than 0, how much of an impact does `(? > 0)` have to always (as far as I have tested) output 1?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 2, j = 5;
    double k = 5.0;
    cout << (i%j > 0) << " " << (i/k >0) << " " << (100>0) << endl;
    cout << (i%j) << " " << (i/k) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 1 1
2 0.4
```

Comment: 1 = true, 0 = false, that's result of comparison. Am I missing something?

Comment: `i > 0` returns a `bool`ean value (true or false). `cout`'s `<<` operator interprets that `bool` as an `int` (or some other integral type) and prints the value `0` for `false` and `1` for `true`.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think it turned it into a bool

Answer (score 0):

`(i>0)` returns a boolean `true`/`false`, which is then automatically type-casted to 1 or 0 by `cout`.

Comment: `TRUE/FALSE` in caps could lead to confusion between the macros `TRUE` and `FALSE` vs the boolean keyword/values `true` and `value`.

Comment: @kfsone Thanks, I made the suggested change.

Answer (score 0):

The expressions you use in perentheses are being evaluated as **'true'** or **'false'**, so when the expression is evaluated a true the output is 1, if false the output is 0. If you want you can enable boolalpha, like this:

```
cout << boolalpha << (i % j > 0) << (i / k > 0);// rest of code...
```

The output of this would be:

```
true false
```

Answer (score -3):

Just set boolalpha like that: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/boolalpha/

Comment: Please avoid link only answers. If the link breaks, this will be useless. Make sure to include the pertinent information in the answer.